# Lenovo X1 Carbon key combination for [Insert], [Print Screen], etc

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, lenovo-laptop

Lack of <kbd>Insert</kbd> key (required for Copy/Paste in many Linux programs) kills me.
I once saw this list somewhere, but lost its reference.

Looking for key combination (probably <kbd>Fn</kbd> with something else) of: <kbd>Insert</kbd>, <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>, <kbd>Sys Req</kbd>, <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>, etc.

for Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon. Especially the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Lenovo Manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20170829145042/https://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/x1carbon_2_ug_en.pdf):

- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

  - Has the same function as the <kbd>Break</kbd> key on a conventional keyboard.
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

  - Has the same function as the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key on a conventional keyboard.
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

  - Has the same function as the <kbd>ScrLK</kbd> key on the conventional keyboard.
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

  - Has the same function as the <kbd>Pause</kbd> key on the conventional keyboard.
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

  - Has the same function as the <kbd>SysRq</kbd> key on the conventional keyboard.
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

  - Has the same function as the <kbd>Prt Sc</kbd>  key on a conventional keyboard.
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

  - Has the same function as the <kbd>End</kbd> key on a conventional keyboard.
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

  - Has the same function as the <kbd>Home</kbd> key on a conventional keyboard.
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>

  - Puts the computer to sleep mode. To resume normal operation, press the power button.

Comment: This may be in manual but does not in fact work....

Comment: It does work directly under Windows for me, but naturally it doesn't under a telnet client like Putty

Comment: On my 2016 X1 Carbon, Fn+S is the SysRq (behaves the same as alt+print screen), but Fn+T appears to have no effect. H/E/I have no effect (I have never observed them on the last 3 models of X1, either). The rest continue to work.

Comment: So what should I press to select files in mc? Normally it is the Insert button, but neither Fn+I, nor Esc+I works. Update: I've just found out Ctrl+t works there.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> works directly under Windows for me. However, it wouldn't work under a telnet client like Putty. In the latter case, <kbd>Esc</kbd> acts as the funciton key, eg. <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> = <kbd>Ins</kbd>.